# Fatal error in Xcode - I know the cause but don't know how to fix it

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

code highlighted in green by Xcode (Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSRTUCTION)

```
amountDueLabel.text = String(HomeViewController().getAllowanceDue())
```

the function `getAllowanceDue()`

```
func getAllowanceDue() -> Int{
    var allowance = allowanceTextField.text.toInt()
    return allowance!
}
```

thank you so much!

Go easy on me - I am a beginner in iOS development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift unlike Objective C, you have to explicitly let the compiler know that a variable can be 'nil' in future by marking that variable as optional (?).

`toInt()` method also returns an 'optional Integer value' which means `toInt()` method can also return 'nil' value in case it is not able to convert the supplied string value to integer value.

Here  you are unwrapping the optional Int value with `allowance!` . But before unwrapping the optional value you must check if the optional value is not 'nil'.

```
func getAllowanceDue() -> Int {
    if let allowance = anotherString.toInt() {
        return allowance
    }
    return -1
}
```

By checking `if let allowance = anotherString.toInt()` we are actually using concept of  [Optional Binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) in Swift to check whether optional contains a value.